# Taxonomy field not visible for anonymous users with content create permission

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

When creating a new node, anonymous users can't see taxonomy field but administer can see it.anonymous users have permission to create nodes.

How can I show it to anonymous users?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to give anonymous user the permission of administer taxonomy.